# What is the best way to query timeseries data with cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

My table is a time series one. The queries are going to process the latest entries and TTL expire them after successful processing. If they are not successfully processed, TTL will not set.

The only query I plan to run on this is to select all entries for a given entry_type. They will be processed and records corresponding to processed entries will be expired.

This way every time I run this query I will get all records in the table that are not processed and processing will be done. Is this a reasonable approach?

Would using a listenablefuture with my own executor add any value to this considering that the thread doing the select is just processing.

I am concerned about the TTL and tombstones. But if I use clustering key of timeuuid type is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

You are right one important thing getting in your way will be tombstones. By Default you will keep them around for 10 days. Depending on your access patter this might cause significant problems. You can lower this by setting the directly on the table or change it in the cassandra yaml file. Then it will be valid for all the newly created table `gc_grace_seconds`

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tabProp.html

It is very important that you make sure you are running the repair on whole cluster once within this period. So if you lower this setting to let's say 2 days, then within two days you have to have one full repair done on the cluster. This is very important because processed data will reaper. I saw this happening multiple times, and is never pleasant especially if you are using cassandra as a queue and it seems to me that you might be using it in your solution. I'll try to give some tips at the end of the answer.

I'm slightly worried about you setting the ttl dynamically depending on result. What would be the point of inserting the ttl-ed data that was successful and keeping forever the data that wasn't. I guess some sort of audit or something similar. Again this is a queue pattern, try to avoid this if possible. Also one thing to keep in mind is that you will almost always insert the data once in the beginning and then once again with the ttl should your processing be o.k.

Also getting all entries might be a bit tricky. For very moderate load 10-100 req/s this might be reasonable but if you have thousands per second getting all the requests every time might not be a good idea. At least not if you put them into single partition.

Separating the workload is also good idea. So yes using listenable future seems totally legit.

Setting clustering key to be timeuuid is usually the case with time series thata and I totally agree with you on this one.

In reality as I mentioned earlier you have to to take into account you will be saving 10 days worth of data (unless you tweak it) no matter what you do, it doesn't matter if you ttl it. It's still going to be ther, and every time cassandra will scan the partition will have to read the ttl-ed columns. In short this is just pain. I would seriously consider actually using something as kafka if I were you because what you are describing simply looks to me like a queue.

If you still want to stick with cassandra then please consider using buckets (adding date info to partitioning key and having a composite partitioning key). Depending on the load you are expecting you will have to bucket by month, week, day, hour even minutes. In some cases you might even want to add artificial columns to reduce load on the cluster. But then again this might be out of scope of this question.

Be very careful when using cassandra as a queue, it's a known antipattern. You can do it, but there are a lot of variables and it extremely depends on the load you are using. I once consulted a team that sort of went down the path of cassandra as a queue. Since basically using cassandra there was a must I recommended them bucketing the data by day (did some calculations that proved this is o.k. time unit) and I also had a look at this solution https://github.com/paradoxical-io/cassieq basically there are a lot of good stuff in this repo when using cassandra as a queue, data models etc. Basically this team had zombie rows, slow reading because of the tombstones etc. etc.

Also the way you described it it might happen that you have "hot rows" basically since you would just have one wide partition where all your data would go some nodes in the cluster might not even be that good utilised. This can be avoided by artificial columns.

When using cassandra as a queue it's very easy to mess a lot of things up. (But it's possible for moderate workloads)